# Accessing a website and submitting info via python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a script in Python that accesses an 'anonymous email' website then fills in the necessary info and submits it. All it requires is a 'To', 'Subject' and 'Message' field followed by a 'submit' button. I'm new to python so I'd like to get some pointers, not necessarily a straight answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the email package for Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html). Also, as a rule of thumb, do some research online before coming here. I think this community is intended for problems that cannot be solved by Googling "Python e-mail library". Not meaning to be snarky, but you might find you get down voted otherwise.

Comment: I sorta anticipated that (the down voting). The thing is, there's so much info that it becomes overwhelming if you have no idea where to start. That's why I brought the question here. Thanks for the pointers!